# ReplyTo with SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendgrid

Is there any way to add ReplyTo using sendgrid library??

I'm using following code, but it not works:

```
                    SendGridMessage myMessage= new SendGridMessage();

                    myMessage.AddTo(toEmail);
                    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("", "");
                    myMessage.Subject = subject;
                    myMessage.Html = body;


                    MailAddress rpto = new MailAddress("test@test.com");                         

                   **//This not works**
                    myMessage.ReplyTo = rpto;


                    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("", ""); 
                    var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);     

                    transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

**Error:**
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' to 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress[]'

Searching I found at https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/58 is not implemented.

Any workaround about this??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ReplyTo` is expecting an array and you are providing just one address.

Try doing:

```
MailAddress rpto = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
var addresses = new [] { rpto };
myMessage.ReplyTo = addresses;
```

However if `ReplyTo` is obsolete, just use the `ReplyToList` and provide it with whatever it's asking for. If it is a list, just create a list with a single element.

```
MailAddress rpto = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
var addresses = new List<MailAddress>();
addresses.Add(rpto);
myMessage.ReplyToList(addresses);
```

Comment: About array you're answer is ok. But ReplyTo is obsolete.  Trying using ReplyToList not implemented in library 'SendGrid.SendGridMessage'. I get return: does not contain a definition for 'ReplyToList' and no extension method 'ReplyToList' accepting a first argument of type 'SendGrid.SendGridMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user2370704 Have you tried updating your library? How did you bring it in, nuget, or download? Try `Update-Package` in pm console, or redownload latest version. For `ReplyTo` is it marked as obsolete and gives a warning, or it prevents compilation?

Comment: I've installed via nuget and it is current version("6.1.0.0"). ReplyTo dont prevent compilation, but it looks like not implemented cause it not works when e-mail arrived.

Comment: So the `ReplyToList` is part of the `MailAddress` class. Try using it there instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist(v=vs.110).aspx